# Font Awesome icons not showing up using Bulma in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome, gatsby, bulma

I am building a website using Gatsby and Bulma. In my `Nav.js` file, where I create a general format for the buttons at the top of the website, I have a few buttons using Bulma to which I would like to add icons inside. I went off the documentation for adding Bulma buttons with Font Awesome Icons: https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/button/. My code is exactly the same, other that the fact that I have my buttons wrapped in an `<a>` tag to link to other pages in my website. I have the included `<script>` file listed in documentation to have Font Awesome Icons available, and my code looks as such:

```
const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: `3rem auto`, maxWidth: 650, padding: `0 1rem` }}>
    <nav>

    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>

        <p class="buttons is-outlined is-centered">
          <a href="/"><button class="button is-outlined"> <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
          </span>
          <span>Home</span>
          </button></a>


          <a href="/projects"><button class="button is-outlined">Projects</button></a>

          <a href="/experience"><button class="button is-outlined">Experience</button></a>
        </p>

      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm not sure if I have the `script` located in the correct part of the file, and I've only tried to put an icon for my Home button which looks like this:

[image]

The gap to the left of the "Home" is where I'm guessing the icon should be. I would appreciate any help as to why the icon is not showing up or is showing up blank. Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With the help of a friend, what solved the issue was putting the `<script>` tag in the `public/index.html` file of the project, and then making an exact copy and naming it `index.html` and putting it in the `static` folder in the project. This way, each time a Gatsby server is ran, it will create a copy of the `index.html` file in the `public` repository *with* the Font Awesome Icon script *included*.

Comment: This isn't the right way to go about it and I would suggest to anyone reading to not follow this approach.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue myself so posting here for anyone that is looking for the answer. There are a few ways to make it work, including using the icons as components with a library such as `react-fontawesome`. However if you're using Bulma then chances are that you specifically *don't want to do that*, instead you want to use the class names.

So first install the package:

```
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Then in your index.js / app.js / any styling wrapper component you have:

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'
```

Here is a Typescript example I have in front of me. This is a wrapper component that imports all my global styles for nested child components to use:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import NavMenu from '../nav-menu';
import Footer from '../footer';
import './layout.css';

const Layout: React.FC<{ light: boolean }> = ({ light, children }) => {
    return (
        <div className="layout-wrapper">
            <NavMenu light={light} />
            {children}
            <Footer light={light} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Layout;
```

Comment: This is the correct approach for production and works wonderfully!